# Power BI: calculate value using data from related table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to calculate the value of item by multiple quantity by unit price from related table.

SALES REPORT

| ITEMS | QTY |
| --- | --- |
| A | 12 |
| B | 30 |
| B | 45 |

UNIT PRICE

| ITEMS | PRICE |
| --- | --- |
| A | $5 |
| B | $9 |

Comment: What issue you are facing? what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relationship set up between the Sales table and the Unit Price table, you can use the [RELATED function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/related-function-dax) to retrieve the price.

Add a DAX calculated column to the SALES REPORT table:

```
Value = Sales[QTY] * RELATED(Products[PRICE])
```

You can use [LOOKUPVALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/lookupvalue-function-dax) to get the result from the other table if you don't have a relationship defined between the tables. As the link says, [RELATED is more efficient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/lookupvalue-function-dax#remarks).

```
Value = Sales[QTY] * LOOKUPVALUE(Products[PRICE],Products[ITEMS],Sales[ITEMS])
```

Answer (score 0):

If your schema is like this
[image: S1]

Use this measure

```
Measure = 
SUMX ( RELATEDTABLE ( 'SALES REPORT' ), 'SALES REPORT'[QTY] )
    * SUM ( 'UNIT PRICE'[PRICE] )
```

[image: S2]